# Determine whether a mysqli_result instance has been prepared?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is it possible, and if so then how, to determine whether an instance of mysqli_result has been prepared or not?

The code below illustrates the problem. After the instance has been created with mysqli::stmt_init and passed to some function that may or may not prepare it the code should branch conditionally depending on whether or not it was prepared. If someone knows how to accomplish this I would love to know. Thanks.

```
function toPrepareOrNotToPrepareThatIsTheQuestion($stmt) {
    if (rand() % 2) {
        $stmt->prepare('DELETE FROM foo WHERE bar = ?');
    }
}

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
toPrepareOrNotToPrepareThatIsTheQuestion($stmt);

if ( /* $stmt is not prepared yet */ ) {
    $stmt->prepare('DELETE FROM baz WHERE bar = ?');
}

$stmt->bind_param('i', (int) $bar);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `stmt_init` says:

> Any subsequent calls to any mysqli_stmt function will fail until mysqli_stmt_prepare() was called.

You can use this fact to determine whether or not your statement was prepared. You can attempt some harmless (pointless, but unlikely to fail if the statement was prepared) call, something like

```
$is_prepared = $stmt->attr_set(MYSQLI_STMT_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, MYSQLI_CURSOR_TYPE_NO_CURSOR);
// MYSQLI_CURSOR_TYPE_NO_CURSOR is the default value.
// Unless you have actually need it to be something else this should have no effect
```

If it hasn't been prepared, you'll get a warning and `$is_prepared` will be null, otherwise it will be true.

Answer (score 1):

Top comment on [PHP documentation for stmt_init](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php) states `you can use $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(); directly without stmt-init()`. It then says `i think there is no need for stmt-init` which I cannot agree with more, especially in your case.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$stmt = false;

// something could possibly happen here
// which results in $stmt becoming an object via $stmt = $mysqli->prepare()

// $stmt is not set yet
if (!$stmt) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM baz WHERE bar = ?');
}

$stmt->bind_param('i', (int) $bar);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: My example code is just to illustrate what I would want to be able to do. My actual case is of course a lot more complicated. A reference to the mysqli_stmt gets passed on to a number of other objects each of which might or might not need to execute it depending on what happens at runtime. If none of them needs to execute it I want to prevent the overhead of preparing it on the MySQL server. If more than one of them need to execute it I want to prevent the overhead of preparing the same statement multiple times.

Comment: That sounds like a very questionable structure. You are passing mysqli statement objects to classes with the hope/expectation that there is an ability for these classes to know if a query was executed? The statement object for one is changing every time you possibly prepare but don't execute something. The only thing I can think would be to hit a centralized service-like class that executes db queries, where it would be able to more easily realize if a query was executed.

Comment: I don't want to hope that the classes will know. I want to be sure that they will know. Hence my question. This can easily be accomplished by passing a reference to an array around that contains the mysqli_stmt and a boolean flag. However, if it can be determined directly from the mysqli_stmt that would be easier. The structure is not that questionable to be honest as the reference is stored in protected properties, i.e. it is an implementation detail that users of the classes don't need to worry about.